# Should I trust AIC value or the p-value of linear regression model?

Tags: regression, p-value, model-selection, aic

I have a linear model and when i run the stepwise variable selection, i got:

```
Start:  AIC=166.27
Y ~ A + B + C + D + E

                   Df Sum of Sq    RSS    AIC
<none>                          1466.0 166.27
- B                1     81.08 1547.0 166.64
- D                1    436.35 1902.3 175.73
- A                1    498.93 1964.9 177.16
- E                1    559.51 2025.5 178.49
- C                1   1334.19 2800.2 192.74
```

but its summary states that:

```
                 Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)      65.41682    9.93755   6.583 9.07e-08 ***
A                 -0.22676    0.06305  -3.596 0.000916 ***
B                 -0.33141    0.22860  -1.450 0.155333    
C                 -0.94235    0.16024  -5.881 8.30e-07 ***
D                  0.10382    0.03087   3.363 0.001769 ** 
E                  1.38058    0.36252   3.808 0.000496 ***
```

B is actually not significant!

Comment: Inspect the data before "trusting" any statistical summary.

Comment: @MichaelLew-reinstateMonica the data seems right to me :)

Comment: [You should trust neither.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20836/algorithms-for-automatic-model-selection/20856#20856)